# Python's equivalent Java's function wait(), notify(), synchronized

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I have to write a class in Python 2.7 and I have some problems.
I come from a java background and learned python quite recently

Here is what I would write if i have to do in java

```
public class CommandSender extends Thread {
    private boolean isTimeOut;
    private boolean running;
    private ArrayList<Command> waitingList;

    public CommandSender() {
        running = false;
        waitingList = new LinkedList<Command>();
        isTimeOut = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            synchronized (this) {
                 while (waitingList.isEmpty() && running) {
                     try {
                         wait();
                     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                         ie.printStackTrace();
                     }
                  }
                  while (!waitingList.isEmpty() && running) {
                      currentCmd = waitingList.remove(0);
                      // doSomething(currentCmd)
                  }
             }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void sendCommand(Command cmd) {
        waitingList.add(cmd);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized boolean isTimeOut() {
        return isTimeOut;
    }
}
```

What i have do for the moment

```
class CommandSender(threading.Thread)

     def __init__(self):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.waiting_list = []
         self.running = False
         self.is-time_out = False
         self.my_lock = threading.Lock()

     def run(self):
         self.running = True
         with self.my_lock:
             while len(self.waiting_list) == 0 and self.running:
                 # Don't know what I have to do here
             while len(self.waiting_list) != 0 and self.running:
                 # Do my stuff

     def send_command(self, cmd):
         with self.my_lock:
             self.waiting_list.append(cmd)
             # Notify ?

     def is_time_out(self):
         with self.my_lock:
             return self.is_rime_out
```

I use one lock per instance because there is only one instance of CommandSender

So How to do the wait/notify process ? And are my synchronised block well used ?

Thanks !

Comment: A side note: I personally think it is a better pattern to use lock objects (regardless of language) rather than synchronize the entire object. Otherwise, if ever your object is used for synchronization externally it will lead to strange results.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should be aware of Python's [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) will not allow more than one thread to run Python code at the same time (though threads can run e.g. C code, for example using native code modules if they release the GIL appropriately). If you need to make use of a multicore CPU using Python code, check out the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Now, the direct equivalent is the [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) class. Create an `Event` object, then use `wait` and `set`.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a simple producer-consumer queue. In Java you should consider using [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). In Python you may use a [Queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) class for threaded programs, and [multiprocessing.Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) class for programs using `multiprocessing`.

Unless this is homework and you are required to implement the code yourself using some specific locking mechanism. The simplest way I know to implement a producer-consumer queue is using two or three semaphores:

- One semaphore to count the number of elements in the queue. Initially zero.
- One semaphore to count the limit/maximum number of elements in the queue, initialized in this maximum number. This is optional if you don't need a limited queue.
- One semaphore, mutex or critical section for shared access to the internal queue/linked list. In Python this is not required for threaded programs since the GIL lets you add elements to a list without the need to synchronize threads.

Comment: It is, but the producer and the consumer are in the same Thread which is different as the Main program.

Basically my main program do stuff while CommandSender send command when it can.

Comment: @Zycho And what's the issue? Care to elaborate? You can add and remove elements from the queue from the same thread.